# UX31E, synaptic touchpad, two finger scrolling, jumping around

Tags: touchpad, scrolling

I have some problem with my ASUS UX31E Synaptic touchpad (Ubuntu 14.04). Unlike many people are having problem getting all the functionalities, I have all them, including 2-finger scrolling, working. But often when I sweep the touchpad with 2 fingers to scroll fast, at the instant my fingers leave the touchpad, it scrolls backward like crazy. I've been trying to recalibrate it with different parameter combinations (EmulateTwoFingerMinZ/MinW, Pressures, ...etc) but still not finding a good set of numbers. Can anybody share a good well-behaved setting? Thank you very much in advance!

Yen-Yung